# Return results with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
async def get_balance(exchange, symbol='BTC/USD'):
    freeBalance = await exchange.fetchBalance()
    symbol1_balance = freeBalance[symbol.split('/')[0]]
    symbol2_balance = freeBalance[symbol.split('/')[1]]
    return symbol1_balance, symbol2_balance

async def get_balances(exchanges):    
    futures = [get_balance(exchange) for exchange in exchanges]
    balances = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    return balances

exchanges = [exchange1, exchange2, ...]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(get_balances(exchanges))
```

But I get the error:

> res = loop.run_until_complete(get_balances(exchanges, symbol))
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Nicolas\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line
> 570, in run_until_complete
> self.run_forever()
>
> File "C:\Users\Nicolas\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line
> 525, in run_forever
> raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
>
> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
>
> **main**:49: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'binance.fetch_balance' was never awaited RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object
> allocation traceback
>
> **main**:49: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'bitfinex.fetch_balance' was never awaited RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object
> allocation traceback

To be clear:
print(exchanges[0].fetchBalance())

> <coroutine object binance.fetch_ticker at 0x000001FE6473BA48>

So the function get_balance is already a coroutine.

I managed to run the first [asyncio-example-gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio-example-gather) except that instead of

```
asyncio.run(main())
```

> File "C:\Users\Nicolas\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 34,
> in run
> "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
>
> RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

But the following works:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
res = loop.create_task(main())
```

I am pretty knew with asynchronous programming, was more using multithreading before. Do you know what's wrong here please?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Is this the whole program? How are you running it?

Comment: I have updated just to show exchanges is a list. I am running it on spyder, line by line and running the cell.

Comment: Maybe your environment is already running the event loop, so instead of `loop.run_until_complete(get_balances(exchanges))` you can just write `await get_balances(exchanges)`?

Comment: I tried async def main(): await get_balances(exchanges) and async def main(): loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(), res = loop.run_until_complete(get_balances(exchanges, symbol)) and I get 225: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
  main()

Comment: But that's not what I meant. I meant that, given that the event loop is running, maybe your spyder environment allows you to just write `await main()` at top-level. If that doesn't work, then you should ask in their user support forums how to run trivial asyncio code. The issue you have is specific to that environment and is not a normal Python or asyncio issue.

Comment: I have edited to specify something. Does it help do detect my problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the *full* traceback, and try to provide a [mcve]. What is the point of ``get_balance(exchange)``? As shown, it is an empty wrapper equivalent to just ``exchange.fetchBalance()``. Can you run other ``asyncio`` coroutines? Can you run ``loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))`` without error?

Comment: I have edited it again. I hope that I did not miss any detail now.

Comment: Any idea, someone?